# Cannot Start/Stop Services using SSMS 2014 (but 2008R2 works)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

In SSMS 2014, when I connect to a server in Object Explorer using my network credentials (I am a domain admin), I can do pretty much everything I would expect as a DBA. But I cannot start/stop/restart services. For instance, if I right-click SQL Server Agent,  the options to Start, Stop, and Restart are greyed out.

Using SSMS 2008R2, from the same client machine using the same credentials connecting to the same server, the options are available and functional when I right-click.

This is true for all servers in our environment.

What do I need to configure in order to be able to manipulate SQL services in SSMS 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce that problem here, but my first suspicion any time a menu option disappears or becomes disabled is **permissions**.

Since you've ruled out that your user can perform these features through other tools, then the difference must be the tool acting on your behalf. Right-click the SSMS shortcut (in some operating systems you'll need <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click) and choose **Run as administrator**.

Comment: I've modified my shortcut so it always runs as administrator.... right-click the shortcut, choose Properties, and on the Compatibility tab check the box for "Run this program as an administrator".